# JSON: Convert numeric array to object

Tags: javascript, jquery, arrays, json

This is the JSON I get when encoding an array using jQuery:

```
{"1":{"name":"11233","po":"121212","po_item_number":"000001","po_item_material_code":"material","po_item_description":"assemble","sales_order":"11000000","sales_order_item":"10","tracable":"sds"},
"2":{"name":"11233","po":"121212","po_item_number":"000001","po_item_material_code":"material","po_item_description":"assemble","sales_order":"11000000","sales_order_item":"10","tracable":"sds"},
"3":{"name":"11233","po":"121212","po_item_number":"000001","po_item_material_code":"material","po_item_description":"assemble","sales_order":"11000000","sales_order_item":"10","tracable":"sds"},
"4":{"name":"11233","po":"121212","po_item_number":"000001","po_item_material_code":"material","po_item_description":"assemble","sales_order":"11000000","sales_order_item":"10","tracable":"sds"},
"5":{"name":"11233","po":"121212","po_item_number":"000001","po_item_material_code":"material","po_item_description":"assemble","sales_order":"11000000","sales_order_item":"10","tracable":"sds"}}
```

But I need an object like this:

```
[{"name":"11233","po":"121212","po_item_number":"000001","po_item_material_code":"material","po_item_description":"assemble","sales_order":"11000000","sales_order_item":"10","tracable":"sds"},
{"name":"11233","po":"121212","po_item_number":"000001","po_item_material_code":"material","po_item_description":"assemble","sales_order":"11000000","sales_order_item":"10","tracable":"sds"},
{"name":"11233","po":"121212","po_item_number":"000001","po_item_material_code":"material","po_item_description":"assemble","sales_order":"11000000","sales_order_item":"10","tracable":"sds"},
{"name":"11233","po":"121212","po_item_number":"000001","po_item_material_code":"material","po_item_description":"assemble","sales_order":"11000000","sales_order_item":"10","tracable":"sds"},
{"name":"11233","po":"121212","po_item_number":"000001","po_item_material_code":"material","po_item_description":"assemble","sales_order":"11000000","sales_order_item":"10","tracable":"sds"}]
```

How can I do that?

Comment: First in not an array. Second is not valid. You might need to wrap it in `[]`

Comment: Above value placed in my hidden text field <input type="hidden" name='xcl_json_val' class='xcl_json_val' value='<?=json_encode($result)?>' />

Answer (score 1):

If your input is a String, then first parse it into the object.

```
var obj = JSON.parse( inputStr );
```

try this (assuming `obj` is the input)

```
var output = Object.keys( obj ).map( function(key){
  return obj[ key ];
})
```

```js
var obj = {
  "1": {
    "name": "11233",
    "po": "121212",
    "po_item_number": "000001",
    "po_item_material_code": "material",
    "po_item_description": "assemble",
    "sales_order": "11000000",
    "sales_order_item": "10",
    "tracable": "sds"
  },
  "2": {
    "name": "11233",
    "po": "121212",
    "po_item_number": "000001",
    "po_item_material_code": "material",
    "po_item_description": "assemble",
    "sales_order": "11000000",
    "sales_order_item": "10",
    "tracable": "sds"
  },
  "3": {
    "name": "11233",
    "po": "121212",
    "po_item_number": "000001",
    "po_item_material_code": "material",
    "po_item_description": "assemble",
    "sales_order": "11000000",
    "sales_order_item": "10",
    "tracable": "sds"
  },
  "4": {
    "name": "11233",
    "po": "121212",
    "po_item_number": "000001",
    "po_item_material_code": "material",
    "po_item_description": "assemble",
    "sales_order": "11000000",
    "sales_order_item": "10",
    "tracable": "sds"
  },
  "5": {
    "name": "11233",
    "po": "121212",
    "po_item_number": "000001",
    "po_item_material_code": "material",
    "po_item_description": "assemble",
    "sales_order": "11000000",
    "sales_order_item": "10",
    "tracable": "sds"
  }
};

var output = Object.keys(obj).map(function(key) {
  return obj[key];
})

console.log(output);
```

Comment: Using your code, its separate all value to single character.

Comment: did you tried the snippet I have attached, what is missing from it?

Comment: @abdulkadhar _" its separate all value to single character"_ Then the input is still JSON and has to be parsed with `JSON.parse(...)` before transforming it with the above script

Comment: @abdulkadhar Oh, I thought your input is a JS object rather than the string. Check the updates.